# Create iCloud folders with files

Tags: objective-c, icloud

I need to create folders with some files in iCloud. Trying the following:

```
NSString *folderName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"folder_%@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

//iCloud folder
NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:folderName]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
//NSLog(@"%@",ubiquitousPackage.relativePath);

File *doc = [[File alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage];

[doc saveToURL:[doc fileURL] forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

    if (success)
    {

    }
}];
```

It returns the error:

> Foundation called mkdir("/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile
>   Documents/6CVKW284XZ~com~cloudmy~rom/Documents/folder_20120209_194803/(A
>   Document Being Saved By klp)"), it didn't return 0, and errno was set
>   to 2.

Comment: You didn't create a folder, but a file with no extension.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to escape the space character in your file name, as in:

```
"(A\ Document\ Being\ Saved\ By\ klp)"
```

?

Comment: Not working. I created directory folder_20120209_194803 on the file system and all saved good. But now I can't get folder.